# Нужны ли запятые в данном предложении?

Tags: запятые

Наш менеджер ответит на любой, интересующий вас, вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

**Наш менеджер ответит на любой интересующий вас вопрос** (= на любой из интересующих вас вопросов).

Запятые не нужны, отношения между определениями **неоднородные**. Первое определение,  выраженное местоименным прилагательным, **относится к сочетанию** причастного оборота и  определяемого существительного.

**Из правил Розенталя:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

1) Определение

Согласованные определения являются неоднородными, если предшествующее определение относится не непосредственно к существительному, а к сочетанию последующего определения с этим существительным.

2) Второе определение выражено причастным оборотом

При таком порядке слов обычно запятая ставится, твёрдый, плохо выбритый подбородок (ср. при другом порядке слов: плохо выбритый твёрдый подбородок).

Но: чёрные появившиеся на скатерти пятна; заячий наполовину потёртый воротник; большой собранный автором материал и т. п. — **первое определение относится к сочетанию второго определения с существительным;**